# How to use variable name within dataframe path

Tags: python, pandas

The only thing I added was the attempted concatenation of the file path.

I am getting an 'unexpected character after line continuation character, and cannot figure out why.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import getpass

user = getpass.getuser()

data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\' + user + '\Desktop\bulk export.xlsx',
                       sheet_name=1,
                       header=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, 
                  columns= [1,'Record Type'])
print (df)
```

Comment: escape character: `r'C:\Users\\'`, same for the other part as well.

Comment: Try [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) too: `pd.read_excel(rf'C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\bulk export.xlsx', sheet_name=1, header=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path

user = getpass.getuser()
my_file = Path(f"C:\\Users\\{user}\\Desktop\\bulk export.xlsx")

data = pd.read_excel (my_file, sheet_name=1, header=0)
```

Comment: why does this work without the 'r' in the front of the path name?

Comment: @anarchocaps, `r` in front of the path makes it a raw string meaning that the \ is treated as literal. In this case \ is also an escape character meaning `"\\"` is literal `"\"`. You can see this by trying `print("\\")`.